# Using Window Functions to search back through rows based on time

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm new to SQL and have been battling for days to understand how to search backwards through previous rows based on time.

I found the Windows Lag Function may help me here but I have not found a way to define a time period for it to search back though.

If I enter: -

```
SELECT food_word_1, 
       date, 
       lead(food_word_1,2) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) as prev_food_word_1 
FROM bookmark 
WHERE mood = 'allergies'"
```

The result looks like the following: -

```
food_word_1 |            date            | prev_food_word_1 
-------------+----------------------------+------------------
 burritos    | 2019-02-01 09:56:40.943341 | 
 burritos    | 2019-02-01 09:56:31.56869  | 
 burritos    | 2019-02-01 09:56:31.34883  | burritos
 cereal bar  | 2019-01-10 07:24:29.602226 | burritos
 almonds     | 2019-01-09 08:37:34.223448 | burritos
 fennel      | 2019-01-09 08:35:44.186134 | cereal bar
```

I get a result searching back 2 rows but what I would like to do is have this searching backwards (lag) for rows 36 hours previous instead of me having to define the number of rows with no time associated with them.

Does anyone know the best approach for this please?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Oracle, because the question was originally tagged Oracle.

Oracle supports `range between` with number ranges, but these can also be used for dates.  Try this:

```
SELECT food_word_1, 
       date, 
       lead(food_word_1) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC RANGE BETWEEN 1.5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prev_food_word_1 
FROM bookmark 
WHERE mood = 'allergies';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for the comment and the idea but I failed to add (sorry) that I am using POSTGRES and after trying this and searching for an equivalent, I could not get it to work. I'm not sure I am going in the right direction with the "lag" function but I will continue to experiment and any further pointer would be very much appreciated.